# Intent Bundle returns Null every time?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I have some extras sent to a new intent. There it grabs the bundle and tests if it is `null`. Every single time it is `null` even though I am able to get the values passed and use them.

Can anyone see what is wrong with the if statement?

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
int picked = b.getInt("PICK");
int correct = b.getInt("CORR");
type = b.getString("RAND");
if(b == null || !b.containsKey("WELL")) {
    Log.v("BUNDLE", "bun is null");
} else {
    Log.v("BUNDLE", "Got bun well");
}
```

EDIT: Heres where the bundle is created.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, app.pack.son.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("PICK", pick);
b.putInt("CORR", corr);
b.putString("RAND", "yes");
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please provide the code which creates (and sends) the bundle.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the problem is that your bundle is `null`. It can't be because you'd get a `NullPointerException` much sooner.

The problem is that your error message is wrong. Change this:

```
if(b == null || !b.containsKey("WELL")) {
    Log.v("BUNDLE", "bun is null");
} else {
    // ...
}
```

To this:

```
if (!b.containsKey("WELL")) {
    Log.v("BUNDLE", "bundle does not contain key WELL");
} else {
    // ...
}
```

And the reason why the bundle doesn't contain this key, is because you didn't add it.

Comment: I want to help you, but I need more information: 1) I need to see the code that puts the extras and raising this activity 2) if I understood right - you say that b is null, but you can get values from it??? it's can't be.. are you absolutely sure it's null? (did you put break point on debug mode and got null?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you test `b == null` after using it, which must be wrong. Also are you missing  the initial `if`?

**After edits**

You don't put "WELL" inside the bundle, so the string "bun is null" is logged. The `b` must be non-null or you would have a crash at your hands. Try changing your `if` sentences to this and report what you get:

```java
if (b == null) {
    Log.v("BUNDLE", "bun is null");
} else if (!b.containsKey("WELL")) {
    Log.v("BUNDLE", "bun doesn't contain WELL");
else {
    Log.v("BUNDLE", "Got bun well");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change your `if` statement to match the log message.  Please run the program and check the log message.

```
if(b == null) {
    Log.v("BUNDLE", "bun is null");
} else {
    if (b.containsKey("WELL")) {
        Log.v("BUNDLE", "Got bun well");
    }
}
```