# Brain Dead Moment: Passing Bundle in an Intent with Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

So I'm getting a null pointer exception on an attempt to retrieve a bundle from the intent that started an activity.

The code in the previous activity is:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
Intent that = new Intent(this, GoogleMapSearchActivity.class);
that.putExtra("bundle", b);
startActivity(that);
```

The called activity attempts to find the bundle with:

```
Bundle bund;
Intent activity = getIntent();
bund = activity.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

Then the null pointer exception pointing at the last line, followed by a very dumb expression on my face and a frustrated feeling in my heart.

```
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.donatorproj/com.example.donatorproj.GoogleMapSearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at com.example.donatorproj.GoogleMapSearchActivity.addInitialDataMarkers(GoogleMapSearchActivity.java:85)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at com.example.donatorproj.GoogleMapSearchActivity.onCreate(GoogleMapSearchActivity.java:78)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-02 01:32:43.249: E/AndroidRuntime(2162):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace, please?

Comment: Not sure but just try `Intent that = new Intent(YourCurrentActivityname.this, GoogleMapSearchActivity.class);` while calling intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
Intent that = new Intent(this, GoogleMapSearchActivity.class);
that.putExtras(b); // formerly that.putExtra("bundle", b);
startActivity(that);

Bundle bund;
Intent activity = getIntent();
bund = activity.getExtras(); // fomerly bund = activity.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

Well my problem went away by simply using the putExtras method instead of putExtra then a call to getBundleExtra with the keyname. I don't really understand why it is the first way I did it won't work though.

Answer (score 2):

Procedure of using bundle:

Bundle for intent:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, A.class);

Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();

extras.putString(key, value);
```

Creating bundle

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);

Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();

mBundle.extras.putString(key, value);

intent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

PutExtra method used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);

intent.putExtra(key, value);
```

Then, in the launched Activity, you would read them via:

```
String values = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your bundle is empty. Try using `hasExtra("bundle")` to check if it has the bundle.

Comment: Did an if statement:   if(activity.hasExtra("bundle")); and now getting a null pointer on the if statement....

Answer (score 0):

I just like listing the individual parameters, e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent (SomeActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("paramName1", theString);
    intent.putExtra("paramName2", "anotherString");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in the launched activity,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        variable1 = extras.getString("paramName1");
        variable2 = extras.getString("paramName2");
    }
```

One of your arguments passed, or the entire bundle, must contain a null value seen at line 78. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106306/intent-bundle-returns-null-every-time?rq=1) may shed light on the issue.
Hope this helps.